# How to enable JAyatana in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I want to have global menu support for Java apps in Ubuntu 16.04. I think jayatana is installed by default in Ubuntu, but it isn't enabled by default. How can I enable it?

Comment: Did you try this article? http://www.webupd8.org/2015/10/ubuntu-1510-and-1504-update-disables.html
Sorry, I'm too busy making an answer out of this article :-/

Comment: I tried what was suggested in webupd8 article and worked like a charm for me.

Comment: the suggested duplicate doesn't seem to have a working solution

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 32bit:

```
gedit ~/.AndroidStudio2.1/studio.vmoptions
```

For Ubuntu 64bit:

```
gedit ~/.AndroidStudio2.1/studio64.vmoptions
```

Add the following line in the opened file and save the file.

```
-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```